# MySQL complex conditional select query

Tags: mysql, rdbms

I have a table where I am storing result of teams. A team `id` can be `homeTeam` or `awayTeam`. I want to retrieve the last 5 matches that a `team` has played.

Please see my SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/701305/1

[image]

If you see the result, here I am trying to get the last 5 matches stats of `team id 165`

In the first row, 165 is a `homeTeam` and you can see `homeTeamPoint(3)>awayTeamPoint(0)` so in this case I want to return `W` similarly if the team lose then it should `L` and if same points then `D`

So out put I am expecting can be in two ways

Out put : `W,L,W,W,L` 
or 
Out put can be multiple rows..

Please help me it's too complex for me.

Thank you so much.

Comment: What is your MySQL server version ?

Comment: Server version: 5.6.38-83.0-log - Percona Server (GPL), Release 83.0, Revision dc97471bd40

Comment: Shouldn't your streak be W,L,W,W,L ?

Comment: Sorry yes @MadhurBhaiya. Edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple [`CASE .. WHEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) statement(s) to get **result** from the perspective of `team_id = 65`.

```
SELECT 
  homeTeam, 
  awayTeam, 
  homeTeamPoint, 
  awayTeamPoint, 
  CASE 
    WHEN homeTeamPoint = awayTeamPoint 
      THEN 'D'
    WHEN `homeTeam` = 165 AND homeTeamPoint > awayTeamPoint 
      THEN 'W'
    WHEN `homeTeam` = 165 AND homeTeamPoint < awayTeamPoint 
      THEN 'L'
    WHEN `awayTeam` = 165 AND homeTeamPoint < awayTeamPoint 
      THEN 'W'
    WHEN `awayTeam` = 165 AND homeTeamPoint > awayTeamPoint 
      THEN 'L'
  END AS result   
FROM fixtureandresults 
WHERE (`homeTeam` = 165 OR awayTeam=165) 
  AND over = 1 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5
```

### [DB Fiddle DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u8ER3SD3oFEKkcewY6Yx4u/0)

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know that I could use AND inside when. Thank you so much. :) It works.

Comment: @sadek Happy to help :)